# how can I expect alias names for @requestBody bean class fields from user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was working on some `spring-boot` controller. I am exposing a post API. In that I have `@RequestBody OrdersBean bean` as parameter. Post Api code below:

**Controller api post method**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
    @PostMapping(value="postOrder",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler> postOrder_(@RequestBody OrdersBean bean){
        long l_time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Orders model = new Orders();
        Customer customer = cusRepo.findOne(bean.getCustomerId());
        if(customer==null) {
            return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed, "no such customer",commonsUtil.latency(l_time_start)+" ms"),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);          
        }
        User user = usrRepo.findOne(bean.getUserId());
        if(user==null) {
            return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed, "no such user",commonsUtil.latency(l_time_start)+" ms"),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);          
        }
        Payments payments = payRepo.findOne(bean.getPaymentsId());
        if(payments==null) {
            return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed, "no such payment",commonsUtil.latency(l_time_start)+" ms"),HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);           
        }

        model.setCustomer(customer);
        model.setUser(user);
        model.setPayments(payments);
        model.setNotified(bean.getNotified());
        model.setOrderActive(bean.getOrderActive());
        model.setOrderDate(bean.getOrderDate());
        model.setOrderPayload(bean.getOrderPayload());
        model.setOrderStatus(bean.getOrderStatus());

        Orders model2 = ordRepo.saveAndFlush(model);
        if(model2!=null)
        return new  ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.OK, ResponseStatusEnum.SUCCESSFUL, ApplicationResponse.SUCCESSFUL, "order created",commonsUtil.latency(l_time_start)+" ms"),HttpStatus.OK);
        else
            return  new ResponseEntity<CoreResponseHandler>(new SuccessResponseBeanRefined(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ResponseStatusEnum.FAILED, ApplicationResponse.Failed,"exception",commonsUtil.latency(l_time_start)+" ms"),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

**OrderBean class**

```
import java.util.Date;
public class OrdersBean implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7567253331511523847L;
    
    private int customer_Id; // I want user to use alias as cust.id
    private int payments_Id; // I want user to use alias as pay.id
    private int user_Id; // I want user to use alias as usr.id
    private String orderPayload;
    private Date orderDate;
    private String orderStatus;
    private Byte notified;
    private Byte orderActive;

    public OrdersBean_() {
    }

    public OrdersBean_(int customer_Id, int payments_Id, int user_Id, String orderPayload, Date orderDate,
            String orderStatus, Byte notified, Byte orderActive) {
        this.customer_Id = customer_Id;
        this.payments_Id = payments_Id;
        this.user_Id = user_Id;
        this.orderPayload = orderPayload;
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
        this.notified = notified;
        this.orderActive = orderActive;
    }

    public int getCustomer_Id() {
        return customer_Id;
    }

    public void setCustomer_Id(int customer_Id) {
        this.customer_Id = customer_Id;
    }

    public int getPayments_Id() {
        return payments_Id;
    }

    public void setPayments_Id(int payments_Id) {
        this.payments_Id = payments_Id;
    }

    public int getUser_Id() {
        return user_Id;
    }

    public void setUser_Id(int user_Id) {
        this.user_Id = user_Id;
    }

    public String getOrderPayload() {
        return orderPayload;
    }

    public void setOrderPayload(String orderPayload) {
        this.orderPayload = orderPayload;
    }

    public Date getOrderDate() {
        return orderDate;
    }

    public void setOrderDate(Date orderDate) {
        this.orderDate = orderDate;
    }

    public String getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

    public Byte getNotified() {
        return notified;
    }

    public void setNotified(Byte notified) {
        this.notified = notified;
    }

    public Byte getOrderActive() {
        return orderActive;
    }

    public void setOrderActive(Byte orderActive) {
        this.orderActive = orderActive;
    }


}
```

in above bean class I have below fields

```
private int customer_Id; // I want user to use alias as cust.id
private int payments_Id; // I want user to use alias as pay.id
private int user_Id; // I want user to use alias as usr.id
```

Is it possible for user when consuming my API, he can change the field names as provided in comments above.. like below `JsonObject`

```
{
"cust.id" : 122,
"pay.id" : 678,
"usr.id" : 190,
.
.
.
}
```

Is there any special annotations that I can use for those fields to give them alias names for user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes by doing this:

```
    @JsonProperty("cust.id")
    private int customerId;

    @JsonProperty("pay.id")
    private int paymentsId;

    @JsonProperty("usr.id")
    private int userId;
```